# Bootstrap - Customise Table Row Highlight Class for One Page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Bootstrap table that allows users to select rows which adds the `class="success"` to the select Row. I'm using the defaults for the contextual classes:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#tables-contextual-classes

but the customer would like, just for this particular page, to have the success be a more brighter green that stands out more.

Here's an example of the table:

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th scope="col">Serial #</th>
    <th scope="col">Product Code</th>
    <th scope="col">ID</th>
    <th scope="col">Description</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col">Select</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="success" id="PZs456">
      <td>ZK2342MFM</td>
      <td>JMPG</td>
      <td>98651217</td>
      <td>Keyboard - Bluetooth</td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select</button> 
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What's the best way to change the 'success' colour so it's a brighter green just for this page without changing the Bootstrap CSS itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.new-green {
  background: #00ff00 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th scope="col">Serial #</th>
    <th scope="col">Product Code</th>
    <th scope="col">ID</th>
    <th scope="col">Description</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col">Select</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr class="success" id="PZs456">
      <td>ZK2342MFM</td>
      <td>JMPG</td>
      <td>98651217</td>
      <td>Keyboard - Bluetooth</td>

      <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm new-green">Select</button></td>



    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

I do not know if this is a best way but since there are a lot of !important things in bootstrap why dont you use your own as new class?